# C# No Browser Cookies After a Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, cookies

I am trying to implement a SSO cross-domain solution.

When a user tries to login on domain A, he is redirected to a single sign on website which will validate his credentials and write an authentication cookie on this domain, (let´s call it the SSO domain). I am using the following code to write on the cookie:

```
public static void WriteAuthenticationTokenToCookie(HttpContextBase    httpContext, string authenticationToken)
       {
           HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie("_token", authenticationToken);
           authenticationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
           httpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(authenticationCookie);

       }
```

Later, the user tries to access an authenticated page on domain B. The user will be redirected to the SSO domain which will verify if the authentication cookie has any value and return it back to domain B, it is has.

When I open the browser inspector tool, I can see that the authentication cookie on the SSO website is set, since I logged in on domain A, however, when domain B redirects to the SSO domain, I use the code HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("_token") to try and get the value of the cookie but to no avail. It's as if the cookie doesn't exist.
On further inspection, I notice that there is only the asp.net session cookie available on that request.

My goal is to get the value of the cookie on the SSO domain which sadly I haven't been able to accomplish.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without further information. I suggest you use fiddler (or another http traffic sniffer) to capture the requests/responses and verify a) you're setting the cookie b) you're not unsetting the cookie. Also note cookie have flags http-only (not accesible via javascript)/secure-only (can be transferred over https)/path property - root path for which the cookie is valid and domain - cookies are only valid for given domain (and optionally its subdomains).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have verified that I am indeed setting the cookie and that I do not unset it. (I refresh the SSO domain web page or open another tab and check the browser cookies). In regards to the cookie flag, I only use the code that I have provided which means that all the default values will be used (no http/https-only limitation and path set to all pages).